# Why is my ng-if in td having unexpected results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Maybe I am completely confused how `td` works as I haven't used tables in my code for yeeaars (strong `div` believer), or maybe I am confused on how `ng-if` is attempting to separate my data.

Either way, I am not getting my expected results, but there is otherwise nothing wrong with the code, I think my logic is just off.

Here is a working Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/LoMEMBYc6kUodb9tcbfM?p=preview

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks">
      <td ng-if="z.id=='color'" class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a></td>
      <td ng-if="z.id==''" class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The ultimate end result is to have every other `td` a different color, however I realize that the current logic is going to put the colored `td` on the left and the non-colored `td` on the right. But that was the object I was working with before I realized I needed two separate columns, finding the need for a table in the first place.

But anyway, what is not working then is that.. well they are still stacked. I would expect to see the colored `td` on the left-hand side of the table and the non-colored `td` on the right-hand side of the table.

Where's the err in my logic?

Comment: This what you're looking for? http://plnkr.co/edit/VeXBJcf3naI5bRttQ1Pt?p=preview

Comment: z.id is either equal to color, or an empty string, but can't be both at the same time. So every tr will have at most one cell. You need two cells in every row: one blank and one filled, or vice-versa.

Comment: @tymeJV *jaw drop* YES! Lemme implement it into my code and see if it has similar results. The plunker is a dummied down version. I am sure it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model seems to be the source of the confusion. You have a simple array, so each `td` will be in the same row. If you create a 2d array, you can make a new row for each inner array:

```
$scope.waiverModalLinks =[
    [
       {title:"1", link:"", id:"color"},
       {title:"2", link:"", id:""}
   ],
   [
       {title:"3", link:"", id:"color"},
       {title:"4", link:"", id:""}
   ]
];
```

And a simpler repeater:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in waiverModalLinks">
  <td ng-repeat="z in row" class="{{z.id}}">
    <a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VeXBJcf3naI5bRttQ1Pt?p=preview

Comment: Just answer me one question because I have never seen this before. What are you doing with the object with the extra `[`? I have to put those in then every 2 items? What is it doing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`z.id` is either equal to `'color'`, or an empty string, but can't be both at the same time. So every row will have *at most* one cell:

- if z.id is equal to `color`, the generated dom will be

  ```
  <tr ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks">
      <td class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a></td>
      <!-- removed second td -->
  </tr>
  ```
- if z.id is equal to `''`', the generated dom will be

  ```
  <tr ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks">
      <!-- removed first td -->
      <td class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a></td>
  </tr>
  ```

You need *two* cells in every row: one blank and one filled, or vice-versa:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="z in waiverModalLinks">
      <td ng-if="z.id==''"></td>
      <td class="{{z.id}}"><a href="{{z.link}}">{{z.title}}</a></td>
      <td ng-if="z.id=='color'"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ohhh I get it. Once it meets the criteria of the `ng-if` it moves onto the next iteration, thus only outputting one at a time. Makes sense, but perhaps then I was going about this all wrong because look at what it does with the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LoMEMBYc6kUodb9tcbfM?p=preview. But, you did actually answer the question which was why is it having unexpected results. For that, +1!

Comment: No, it doesn't move to the next iteration. Every ng-if is evaluated. And if the condition is false, the <td> is removed from the DOM (I replaced the removed td by a comment in my answer to let you understand). So every <tr> ends up with just one <td>.